# VC++ 2013 runtime ClickOnce bootstrap package

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, clickonce, visual-studio-2017

Running visual studio 2017, and I need to use VC++ 2013 as a prerequisite in a ClickOnce project.  However I am unable to find the package online anywhere, and am not able to install visual studio 2013.

What do the product.xml and package.xml files look like for the VC++ 2013 bootstrapper package?  (someone may still have 2013 installed).

(before the question is closed, this would be a very useful resource for anyone else looking for it...as it doesn't exist online anywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the files - posting here for reference:

**Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Libraries (x86)**

***product.xml***

```
  <!-- These checks determine whether the package is to be installed -->
  <InstallConditions>
    <BypassIf Property="VCRedistInstalled" Compare="ValueGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="3"/>
    <!-- Block install if user does not have admin privileges -->
    <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
    <!-- Block install on Win95 -->
    <FailIf Property="Version9X" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="4.10" String="InvalidPlatformWin9x"/>
    <!-- Block install on Vista or below -->
    <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="6.00" String="InvalidPlatformWinNT"/>
  </InstallConditions>

  <ExitCodes>
    <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
    <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
    <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
  </ExitCodes>

</Command>
```

***package.xml***

```
<!-- Defines a localizable string table for error messages-->
<Strings>
    <String Name="DisplayName">Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Libraries (x86)</String>
    <String Name="Culture">en</String>
    <String Name="AdminRequired">You do not have the permissions required to install Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Libraries (x86). Please contact your administrator.</String>
    <String Name="InvalidPlatformWin9x">Installation of Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Libraries (x86) is not supported on Windows 95. Contact your application vendor.</String>
    <String Name="InvalidPlatformWinNT">Installation of Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Libraries (x86) is not supported on Windows NT 4.0. Contact your application vendor.</String>
    <String Name="GeneralFailure">A failure occurred attempting to install Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Libraries (x86).</String>
    <String Name="VCRedistExe">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320712&amp;clcid=0x409</String>
</Strings>
```

Comment: Could you post the complete files by chance?